# check a list of strings with list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I want to filter a list of strings that includes any specific string with using list comprehension. I tried following the code, but it didn't work.

```
ignore_paths = ['.ipynb_checkpoints', 'New', '_calibration', 'images']
A = [x for x in lof1 if ignore_paths not in x]
```

but when I try with one string, it will work:

```
A = [x for x in lof1 if 'images' not in x]
```

in fact, I want to define a list of a forbidden path (or string) and check if there is a certain path that exists, then ignore that.

I can do that with normal for and if loop and check one by one, but it is not fast. I am looking for a fast way because I need to check around 150k paths.

Thanks

EDIT:
To make it clear, if I had a list of files as below:

```
lof1 = ['User/images/20210701_151111_G1100_E53100_r121_g64_b154_WBA0_GA0_EA0_6aa87af_crop.png', 'User/images/16f48a97-7111-4f66-92cc-dc7329e7ec92.png', 'User/images/image_2022_06_21-11_41_04_AM.png']
```

I need to return an empty list since all of the elements contain `'images'`

Comment: Try: `A = [x for x in lof1 if x not in ignore_paths]`

Comment: Try `A = [x for x in lof1 if x not in ignore_paths]`

Comment: This called a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have duplicates? if not, you can use sets which will be very fast

```
allowed = set(lof1) - set(ignore_paths)
```

Comment: Even if `lof1` is not a set, using one for `ignore_paths` will probably be faster.

Comment: I tried that, but it will return all lists: `lof1 = ['User/images/20210701_151111_G1100_E53100_r121_g64_b154_WBA0_GA0_EA0_6aa87af_crop.png', 'User/images/16f48a97-7111-4f66-92cc-dc7329e7ec92.png', 'User/images/image_2022_06_21-11_41_04_AM.png']`
`set(lof1) - set(ignore_paths)`
Since some of them contain 'images' it should return a blank list

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
A = [x for x in lof1 if x not in ignore_paths]
```

Comment: I tried that, but it will return all lists:
`A = ['User/images/20210701_151111_G1100_E53100_r121_g64_b154_WBA0_GA0_EA0_6aa87af_crop.png', 'User/images/16f48a97-7111-4f66-92cc-dc7329e7ec92.png', 'User/images/image_2022_06_21-11_41_04_AM.png']`
`[x for x in A if x not in ignore_paths]`

Comment: Since some of them contain 'images' it should return a blank list